# Problem is unsatisfiable for same constraint defined differently

Tags: model, constraints, consistency, minizinc

I am a beginner in minizinc and trying to define a constraint without using mod function for multiples of 4 in range 0 to 10.

This works:

```
var 0..10: x;
array[1..8] of int: not_div_by_4 = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 ]; 
constraint forall (i in 1..length(not_div_by_4))(x != not_div_by_4[i]);
```

While, this does not work and claims it to be unsatisfiable with a model inconsistency warning (which is a clue, I suppose):

```
var 0..10: x;
array[1..3] of int: div_by_4 = [ 0, 4, 8 ]; 
constraint forall (i in 1..length(not_div_by_4))(x == not_div_by_4[i]);
```

Any idea what is wrong with the second way of defining the constraint?

Answer (score 3):

Your second code requires a variable to be equal to several different values at the same time. This is not satisfiable and detected as such at compile-time.

The following works:

```
var 0..10: x;
array[1..3] of int: div_by_4 = [ 0, 4, 8 ]; 
constraint exists (i in 1..length(div_by_4))(x == div_by_4[i]);
```

A shorter way:

```
var 0..10: x;
constraint x in {0, 4, 8};
```